# What is the difference if TestFixture attribute is used or not

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, installation

I cant see any difference in behaviour for class that has `TestFixture` attribute and not. All `TearDown` and `SetUp` are working in the same way. Is there any reason except semantics for this attribute usage?

Comment: Interesting question. NUnit seems to recognise fixtures that don't have the attribute and run them correctly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Is purely a convenience, beginning with NUnit 2.5, if a class satisfies the conditions to be a test fixture and specifies at least a method marked with `Test`, `TestCase` or `TestCaseSource` than that class is treated as a test fixture.

The `TestFixture` attribute is required however for parameterized or generic test fixture because in that case you also specify additional information through the attribute (parameters/concrete types).

More information about the specific requirements is available at [TextFixtureAttribute (NUnit 3 Documentation)](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) and
[TestFixtureAttribute (NUnit 2.0 / 2.5)](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5)

Answer (score 16):

If you use `[TestFixture]` you have to put up with that voice in the back of your head saying "Hmm, this is a test class, not really a test *fixture*" and wonder how they got this annotation wrong.

See [Why testFixture instead of testClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177282/why-testfixture-instead-of-testclass).

Comment: Plus one for making me laugh after a long day of working on [TestFixture] tests.